# Convert UUID to string in Django queryset

Tags: json, django, uuid

I have a model with a UUID as primary key.

```
class Books(models.Model):
        id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
        title = .....
```

And I have a simple query:

```
results = Books.objects.all()
```

All is working fine in terms of saving and retrieving data, but part of the record editing process requires storing records in the session variables which means I get the `'UUID('…') is not JSON serializable'` error.

It seems to me, that the simplest answer is to convert the UUID objects to strings immediately after making the initial query, thus preventing multiple changes elsewhere.  Does that sound logical? If so, I assume I could do it with some sort of list comprehension.  Could someone help with the syntax please? Or direct me on the approach if preferred!
Many thanks.

Comment: did your tried [**`Cast()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function?

Comment: I think that looks like the answer. Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
#you have to use

import json

results = Books.objects.all().values('id')

json_str = json.dumps(results)
```